# How do I test a data API (Youtube Data API) with fake data?

Tags: api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am currently working with the YouTube Data API and do not understand how I can test my calls. For instance, I have a call that retrieves all donations made during a YouTube livestream. Without having to create a livestream and donate to myself, how can I create some sample data for testing?

Comment: As far as I know YouTube doesn't provide sample data even if they describe precisely what you could get (example for a [video resource](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos)).